# How can I change default owner when defining new tasks, if multiple accounts are configured?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-office-2013

In Outlook 2013, how can I change default owner when defining new tasks, if multiple accounts are configured? It seems to select always the same owner and there's no way I can change it...

This is quite annoying, because the default owner is an Exchange account, so new tasks are sent to another user who is sharing the same account with me.

I have tried googling for an answer, but with no luck by now...

---

EDIT:

**Please note:** I'd like to specify which of my accounts is the task owner when the task is created, not to change ownership of an existing task. In particular, the only Exchange account **must NOT** be the default new tasks owner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you use the "assign task" function, and then that person accepts it, the owner then becomes them.

Screenshot below (It's 2016 but will work just the same).

[image]

Comment: I understand but I'm not looking for a way to change ownership, I want to create a new task with a specific owner. I have multiple accounts in outlook, but the owner set to new task is always the Exchange one.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013:

File > Options > Mail > Send messages section > Always use the default account when composing new messages

This will help both  the default sender when opening a new email and also the owner for new tasks

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem although I want my Exchange account to be my default account. so far I've learned that whichever account you add first becomes your default place for tasks and calendar. so add your non exchange account first and then your exchange account so your default calendar will be saved on your computer.